# ManagementObjectCollection count property leaks?

Tags: memory-leaks, wmi, idisposable, enumerator

Just recently a few colleagues of mine helped out with narrowing down a memory leak. One of the problems was found in Microsoft's code. This is from reflector showing that the enumerator will leak.

Here the count property calls getenumerator but never checks for Idisposable:

```
public int Count
{
    get
    {
        if (this.isDisposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(name);
        }
        int num = 0;
        IEnumerator enumerator = this.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            num++;
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

This is the ManagementObjectCollection's GetEnumerator just to show the type returned is a ManagementObjectEnumerator.

```
public ManagementObjectEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    if (this.isDisposed)
    {
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(name);
    }
    if (!this.options.Rewindable)
    {
        return new ManagementObjectEnumerator(this, this.enumWbem);
    }
    IEnumWbemClassObject ppEnum = null;
    int errorCode = 0;
    try
    {
        errorCode = this.scope.GetSecuredIEnumWbemClassObjectHandler(this.enumWbem).Clone_(ref ppEnum);
        if ((errorCode & 0x80000000L) == 0L)
        {
            errorCode = this.scope.GetSecuredIEnumWbemClassObjectHandler(ppEnum).Reset_();
        }
    }
    catch (COMException exception)
    {
        ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(exception);
    }
    if ((errorCode & 0xfffff000L) == 0x80041000L)
    {
        ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo((ManagementStatus) errorCode);
    }
    else if ((errorCode & 0x80000000L) != 0L)
    {
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(errorCode);
    }
    return new ManagementObjectEnumerator(this, ppEnum);
}
```

This showing that it is disposable:

```
public class ManagementObjectEnumerator : IEnumerator, IDisposable
{
    // Fields
    private bool atEndOfCollection;
    private uint cachedCount;
    private IWbemClassObjectFreeThreaded[] cachedObjects;
    private int cacheIndex;
    private ManagementObjectCollection collectionObject;
    private IEnumWbemClassObject enumWbem;
    private bool isDisposed;
    private static readonly string name;

    // Methods
    static ManagementObjectEnumerator();
    internal ManagementObjectEnumerator(ManagementObjectCollection collectionObject, IEnumWbemClassObject enumWbem);
    public void Dispose();
    protected override void Finalize();
    public bool MoveNext();
    public void Reset();

    // Properties
    public ManagementBaseObject Current { get; }
    object IEnumerator.Current { [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")] get; }
}
```

Though enumerators that are disposable are disposed of properly by foreach statements (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(v=vs.71).aspx), this does not mean that the only case where the enumerator will be used is in a foreach loop.

I know that you can skip the count property and roll your own mechanism for getting the number of objects in the collection by using the enumerator yourself but the question I have is how much unmanaged memory does this leak?